# Linksys AE3000 How to work around?

Tags: wireless, drivers, windows, wine, ndiswrapper

I have a Linksys AE3000 Dual-Band Wireless-N USB Adapter. I need it to work for my Ubuntu 12.04. I have looked up how to work around the fact that Cisco didn't supply a Linux driver but I'm quite new to Ubuntu (a couple of days in fact) so they haven't helped all that much. I have wine and ndiswrapper downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install ubuntu 32bit and install ndiswrapper 1.58rc1 and insert the xp driver.